# Modifying a symlink in python

Tags: python, symlink

How do I change a symlink to point from one file to another in Python?

The [`os.symlink`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink) function only seems to work to create new symlinks.

Answer (score 40):

If you need an atomic modification, unlinking won't work.

A better solution would be to create a new temporary symlink, and then rename it over the existing one:

```python
os.symlink(target, tmpLink)
os.rename(tmpLink, linkName)
```

You can check to make sure it was updated correctly too:

```python
if os.path.realpath(linkName) == target:
    # Symlink was updated
```

According to the documentation for os.rename though, there may be no way to atomically change a symlink in Windows. In that case, you would just delete and re-create.

Comment: Python 3.3 has `os.replace` which can be used instead of `os.rename` to provide the same behaviour on Posix & Windows systems.

Comment: Won't work on Linux systems - needs `replace`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742015/5353461) for a complete solution (including generating a temporary symlink pathname).

Comment: @TomHale, this works fine on my Linux system provided the original file you're overriding is also a symlink (true for me). And unlike your solution it works on Python 2.7.

Comment: Note that 1) `replace` raises `IsADirectoryError` if `linkName` is a directory and `tmpLink` will then need to be deleted. 2) `replace` may fail if the two files are not on the same filesystem. I deal with both cases in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742015/5353461).

Answer (score 34):

A little function for Python2 which tries to symlink and if it fails because of an existing file, it removes it and links again.

```
import os, errno

def symlink_force(target, link_name):
    try:
        os.symlink(target, link_name)
    except OSError, e:
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
            os.remove(link_name)
            os.symlink(target, link_name)
        else:
            raise e
```

For python3 `except` condition should be `except OSError as e:`

Comment: Has a race condition: the known `link_name` could be created again between removal and symlink creation. Try [atomically overwriting the existing symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742015/5353461).

Comment: @TomHale You are right that my solution can fail to do the job. Funny is that your solution can fail, too. ;-)

Comment: While my answer did point out its race condition, you're right that my comment didn't highlight it.  I've now fixed another race in my answer. There is still the *very* unlikely case that a file is created by another process at a randomly generated pathname. Thanks for your comment on my answer, too.

Comment: Would you consider updating to use `except FileExistsError:`? I got a syntax error as written.

Comment: Thanks; with "except OSError as e" it worked for me on RPi Python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 10):

Given `overwrite=True`, this function will safely overwrite an existing file with a symlink.

It is cognisant of race conditions, which is why it is not short, but it is safe.

```
import os, tempfile

def symlink(target, link_name, overwrite=False):
    '''
    Create a symbolic link named link_name pointing to target.
    If link_name exists then FileExistsError is raised, unless overwrite=True.
    When trying to overwrite a directory, IsADirectoryError is raised.
    '''

    if not overwrite:
        os.symlink(target, link_name)
        return

    # os.replace() may fail if files are on different filesystems
    link_dir = os.path.dirname(link_name)

    # Create link to target with temporary filename
    while True:
        temp_link_name = tempfile.mktemp(dir=link_dir)

        # os.* functions mimic as closely as possible system functions
        # The POSIX symlink() returns EEXIST if link_name already exists
        # https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlink.html
        try:
            os.symlink(target, temp_link_name)
            break
        except FileExistsError:
            pass

    # Replace link_name with temp_link_name
    try:
        # Pre-empt os.replace on a directory with a nicer message
        if not os.path.islink(link_name) and os.path.isdir(link_name):
            raise IsADirectoryError(f"Cannot symlink over existing directory: '{link_name}'")
        os.replace(temp_link_name, link_name)
    except:
        if os.path.islink(temp_link_name):
            os.remove(temp_link_name)
        raise
```

Notes for pedants:

1. If the function fails (e.g. computer crashes), an additional random link to the target might exist.
2. An unlikely race condition still remains: the symlink created at the randomly-named `temp_link_name` could be modified by another process before replacing `link_name`.

I raised a [python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue36656) to highlight the issues of `os.symlink()` requiring the target to not exist, where I was advised to raise [my suggestion on the `python-ideas` mailing list](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-ideas/55992/)

Credit to [Robert Siemer’s input](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55742015/3).

Comment: If something “pathological” happens it is better to cycle without sleep, I would argue. Either that or raise an exception (after X iterations)... Anyway... super theoretical... this is why my solution tried only twice.

Comment: @RobertSiemer Thanks for the excellent edits overall. I restored my text about the possible race condition as I believe it is still valid. Please comment if you disagree.

Comment: You love using those words “race condition”, don’t you? ;-)  An “attacking program” with the same permissions could just delete the link after it got properly created (function returned), but before the function caller can do something else. There is nothing to prevent that. I don’t see anything special in case “2.”. It is just another case of “1.”... I used different wording, didn’t I? The function might not just be forcefully “interrupted”; it can also _fail_ for other reasons which would not be “interruptions”.

Comment: ...so if no one interferes, this function will work. – So will my solution. The only advantage of replace() is this guarantee: link_name will either be what is was before, or it will be a link to target with no point in between.

Comment: Won't work for us poor people still on Python 2.7 where "os.replace()" doesn't exist

Comment: What is the while loop for? Under what conditions would it need to repeat?

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt The loop repeats in the unlikely event that a file is created having the same name as the generated temporary filename, and before the `symlink()`.

Comment: After all this bragging about race conditions, ironically, your code has a race condition in the function `tempfile.mktemp()` which [has been deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#deprecated-functions-and-variables) since Python 2.3 and should be no longer used.

Comment: @Jeyekomon there is no race from `mktemp`: any other process creating the file between `mktemp` and `symlink` is handled by `FileExistsError`. The link you post includes the word 'may'. I avoid `mkstemp` as it both creates and opens the file, requiring both closing then deleting the file, which must not exist (prerequisite for a successful `symlink`.)

Answer (score 9):

You could [`os.unlink()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.unlink) it first, and then re-create using [`os.symlink()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.symlink) to point to the new target.

Comment: Has a race condition: the known `link_name` could be created again between removal and symlink creation. Try [atomically overwriting the existing symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742015/5353461).

Answer (score 8):

I researched this question recently, and found out that the best way is indeed to `unlink` and then `symlink`. But if you need just to fix broken links, for example with auto-replace, then you can do `os.readlink`:

```
for f in os.listdir(dir):
    path = os.path.join(dir, f)
    old_link = os.readlink(path)
    new_link = old_link.replace(before, after)
    os.unlink(path)
    os.symlink(new_link, path)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add a raise command in the case when e.errno != errno.EEXIST You don't want to hide an error then:

```
if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
     os.remove(link_name)
     os.symlink(target, link_name)
else:
    raise
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution:

```
while True:
     try:
         os.symlink(target, link_name)
         break
     except FileExistsError:
         os.remove(link_name)
```

However this has a **race condition** when replacing a symlink which should 
*always* exist, eg:

```
 /lib/critical.so -> /lib/critical.so.1.2
```

When upgrading by:

```
 my_symlink('/lib/critical.so.2.0', '/lib/critical.so')
```

There is a point in time when `/lib/critical.so` doesn't exist.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55742015/5353461) avoids the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I like this version more

```
import os
def force_symlink(src, dst):
    if os.path.exists(dst):
        if os.path.realpath(src) == dst:
            return
        os.unlink(dst)
    os.symlink(src, dst)
```